# xml serializing a list of base class

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

Consider the below class structure

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(DerivedClass))]
public class BaseClass
{
    public string mem1;
    public string mem2;
}

public class DerivedClass : List<BaseClass>
{
    public string mem3;
    public string mem4;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DerivedClass obj = new DerivedClass();
        obj.mem3 = "test3";
        obj.mem4 = "test4";
        BaseClass base11 = new BaseClass();
        base11.mem1 = "test1";
        base11.mem2 = "test2";
        obj.Add(base11);
        XElement
           .Parse(XMLSerializerUtil.GetXMLFromObject(obj))
           .Save(@"C:\new_settings1.xml");
    }
}
```

The code for GetXMLFromObject given is below

```
public static string GetXMLFromObject(object instance)
{
        string retVal = string.Empty;
        if (instance != null)
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(instance.GetType());
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(memoryStream, instance);
                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                retVal = new StreamReader(memoryStream).ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

Even after adding the `XmlInclude` attribute, in the generated XML file, the derived class members are not present.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfBaseClass xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <BaseClass>
        <mem1>test1</mem1>
        <mem2>test2</mem2>
    </BaseClass>
</ArrayOfBaseClass>
```

Please let me know, what is missing to include the derived class members in the generated XML file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
DerivedClass : List<BaseClass>
```

For `XmlSerializer`, an item is **either** a list **exclusive-or** an entity. If it looks like a list, then **only** the list-items are serialized; members of the "list" itself *are not serialized*. Basically, don't do that. Instead of *deriving* from a list, *encapsulate* a list:

Also, note that `[XmlInclude(...)]` would expect `DerivedClass : BaseClass`. So, something like:

```
public class SomeType // note DOES NOT INHERIT
{
    private readonly List<SomeOtherType> items = new List<SomeOtherType>();
    public List<SomeOtherType> Items { get { return items; } }
    [XmlElement("mem3")] public string Mem3 {get;set;}
    [XmlElement("mem4")] public string Mem4 {get;set;}
}

public class SomeOtherType
{
    [XmlElement("mem1")] public string Mem1 {get;set;}
    [XmlElement("mem2")] public string Mem2 {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. After including the base class as list, I get the xml as follows.
  <list>
    <BaseClass>
      <mem1>test1</mem1>
      <mem2>test2</mem2>
    </BaseClass>
  </list>

But I need the XML as

<DerivedClass xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <BaseClass>
      <mem1>test1</mem1>
      <mem2>test2</mem2>
    </BaseClass>
    <BaseClass>
      <mem1>test11</mem1>
      <mem2>test21</mem2>
    </BaseClass>
</DerivedClass>

Comment: @prabna if you need to match a specific xml layout, that can be done too - just need to add the right attributes. If you can show the xml, I'll tell you what you need

Comment: Thanks for you help.

After I included the base class as list in the derived class.

<DerivedClass>
  <list>
    <BaseClass>
      <mem1>test1</mem1>
      <mem2>test2</mem2>
    </BaseClass>
    <BaseClass>
      <mem1>test11</mem1>
      <mem2>test21</mem2>
    </BaseClass>
  </list>
</DerivedClass>

But I need it as follows.

<DerivedClass>
    <BaseClass>
      <mem1>test1</mem1>
      <mem2>test2</mem2>
    </BaseClass>
    <BaseClass>
      <mem1>test11</mem1>
      <mem2>test21</mem2>
    </BaseClass>
</DerivedClass>

Comment: @prabna then add `[XmlElement("BaseClass")]` just before the list